# MongoDB $cond issues

Tags: mongodb

How MongoDB $cond works ?

{ $cond: { if: , then: , else:  } }

If the  evaluates to true, then $cond evaluates and returns the value of the  expression. Otherwise, $cond evaluates and returns the value of the  expression.

Comment: Try [Ternary Operation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ternary_operation) there are also plenty of examples in the manual [`$cond`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/). What is not clear?

Comment: *"If the IF evaluates to true, then $cond evaluates and returns the value of the THEN expression. Otherwise, $cond evaluates and returns the value of the ELSE expression."* - you have answered the question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use it $cond like below -

```
domain.Wish.aggregate([{
      $match: {
        event_id: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(wishesObj._id)
      }
        }, {
      $group: {
        _id: 'null',
        amount: {
          $sum: {
            $cond: {
              if: {
                //'wishcontribute':{$ne:'jeenees_price'}
                $ne: ["$wishcontribute", '$jeenees_price']
              },
              then: "$wishcontribute",
              else: 0
            }
          }
        }
      }
        }], function (err, data) {
```